# How to display live data using D3

Tags: d3.js, graph, live-streaming

I have just started using D3 i want to display live server feeds using d3 on my website if possible live stock feeds but there are no tutorials out there explaining how to do this any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi my answer is based on displaying  graph data, you can use

```
// push a new data point onto the back
data.push(random());

// pop the old data point off the front
data.shift();

// transition the line
path.transition().attr("d", line);
```

you can  follow the link [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) with more detail